# How do I monitor valid input with strtok & sscanf

Tags: c

I need to get an input of a string with numbers seperated by white space (could be mutiple spaces).

The code below i wrote prints `Invalid number` only the input is of this form  :

`8a` (char following a number).

For example if I entered `a b c` it won't print `Invalid number` and move on with the program.

Basically I need to check if the string contains **only numbers and white spaces**.

If it dosen't throw an `Invalid number`

If it does - populate *numbers array with these number entered.

```
        printf("Enter numbers:\n");
        fgets (str, sizeof(int)*(size+1)+size*size, stdin);
        token=strtok(str," ");
        for(int i=0; (i<size) && (token!=NULL); i++) {
            if(sscanf(token,"%d%c",&numbers[i],&ch) == 2 && (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n')) {
                printf("Invalid number\n");
                return 0;
            }
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
```

I tried to implement the strspn function as suggested this way :

```
        printf("Enter numbers:\n");
        fgets (str, sizeof(int)*(size+1)+size*size, stdin);
        int index;
        token=strtok(str," ");
        for(int i=0; (i<size) && (token!=NULL); i++) {
            if(sscanf(token,"%d",&numbers[i])==1){
            index=strspn(token,"0123456789");
            }if (str[index]!='\n'&&str[index]!='\0'){
                printf("Invalid number\n");
                return 0;
            }
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
        }
```

for the input : `8 8a 8` the program doesn't print `Invalid number`

Comment: what does line stand for ? could you elaborate ?

Comment: should I write it after the fgets line ?
is the for loop unnecessary ?

Comment: I edited the post .

 if I implemented this function correctly it dosen't produce the solution I need .

Comment: `strspn(token,"0123456789");` - you are missing a space, it's `strspn(token," 0123456789");` `if (str[index]!='\n'&&str[index]!='\0')` - it's `if if (str[index] == '\n' || str[index] == '\0')` the number is invalid, otherwise the number is valid.[man strspn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) [strspn cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn)

Comment: `ctype.h` contians `isspace` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isspace.html and `isdigit` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html, probably make your life easier.

Comment: regarding: `fgets (str, sizeof(int)*(size+1)+size*size, stdin);`  What is the definition of `str`?  What is the value in `size`?   Suggest: `char str[1024];  if( ! fgets (str, sizeof( str ), stdin) ) { perror( "fgets failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `if(sscanf(token,"%d",&numbers[i])==1){`  strongly suggest using the function: `strtol()`  as that will tell you if the whole `token` was numeric or not

Comment: in case im using strtol should I convert it to base 10 ? 
I tried to implement it as follows (on the whole string ):
```if (abs(strtol(str,NULL,10)==9223372036854775807))```

I tried both LONG_MAX for 32bit and 64 bit and both won't detect any chars in the string. 
am I using the wrong base?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use the `%n` specifier to iterate through the string.
`%n` stores the number of characters processed by the scan.
`str + offset` will scan each integer in the string.
If the scan fails, `offset` should be the index of the character causing the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main ( void) {
    char str[SIZE * SIZE] = "";//allow SIZE characters for SIZE number of integers
    int numbers[SIZE] = { 0};

    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    fgets (str, sizeof str, stdin);
    int scanned = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < SIZE && 1 == sscanf ( str + offset, "%d%n", &numbers[i], &scanned)) {
        i++;
        offset += scanned;
    }

    if ( '\n' != str[offset] && '\0' != str[offset] && ' ' != str[offset]) {
        if ( i < SIZE) {
            printf ( "input problem at: %s\n", str + offset);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using `strspn` can also work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main ( void) {
    char str[SIZE * 20] = "";
    int numbers[SIZE] = { 0};

    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    fgets (str, sizeof str, stdin);
    int index = strspn ( str, "\t\r\n 0123456789");//find a non-matching character
    if ( str[index]) {//found one
        printf ( "good: %.*s\n", index, str);
        printf ( "problem: %s\n", str + index);
    }
    else {//str has only digits and whitespace
        int scanned = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < SIZE && 1 == sscanf ( str + offset, "%d%n", &numbers[i], &scanned)) {
            printf ( "number[%d]: %d\n", i, numbers[i]);
            i++;
            offset += scanned;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```